# Empty txInfoSignatories after building transaction with cardano-cli

Tags: plutus, wallet, cardano-cli, testnet

In the Plutus Pionner Lectures, Lars instructed us to use [`txSignedBy`](https://staging.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Contexts.html#v:txSignedBy) in order to ensure that a user signed the transaction. The function tries to find a public key hash in the [`txInfoSignatories`](https://staging.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Api.html#t:TxInfo) list, if it's able to find, it returns True.

Everything was working in the emulator, but now, when I tried to manually build and sign the transaction with cardano-cli, the transaction doesn't appear to add the public key hash from the user who signed it to `txInfoSignatories` and the script validation fails. My question is: how do I add the user pubkeyhash to `txInfoSignatories` with cardano-cli? No information regarding the signature appears when I execute `cardano-cli transaction build -- help`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**------ UPDATE------**

Since version 1.31 of `cardano-cli`, there is the following option to sign the transaction when it is built, so you can avoid that error from the script:

```
--required-signer FILE   Input filepath of the signing key (zero or more)
                         whose signature is required.
```

**-----------------------**

It's related to this bug: [Cli to pass required signer (reqSignerHashes) to plutus script for txInfoSignatories](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/3106)

In a near future, there will be a `--required-signer` option in cardano-cli

As a workaround try to combine `toPubKeyHash` and `txOutAddress` function to get the PubKeyHash from any output.

```
info :: TxInfo
info = scriptContextTxInfo ctx

txOuts :: [TxOut]
txOuts = txInfoOutputs info

outPubKeyHash :: Maybe PubKeyHash
outPubKeyHash = toPubKeyHash $ txOutAddress $ head txOuts
```

Answer (score 1):

@georgeos answer was correct, but from node version 1.32 there is

```
--required-signer-hash HASH
                           Hash of the verification key (zero or more) whose
                           signature is required.
```

(so you don't need to know users signing key, just pass the PubKeyHash)